# How to find out if SQL*Plus is on the call stack?

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

In SQL*Plus, there is a `HOST` [command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/HOST.html#GUID-E6391C3D-E87E-4BCA-B903-A4402D7E399B), to execute an operating system command without leaving SQL*Plus or to display an operating system prompt.

So, if I connect from the Unix command line to SQL*Plus

```
myunixuser ~$ sqlplus user/password@mydb
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 24 21:01:56 2020

SQL>
```

Now, if I type `HOST`, I am back to the shell:

```
SQL> HOST
myunixuser ~$
```

And if I type `exit` on the command line, I am back to SQL*Plus, no surprise there.

I cannot distinguish the original command line and the shell opened by SQL*Plus. 
Is it possible to find out if SQL*Plus is on the call stack, with potentially an open database transaction?

Quite possibly, this is more a question about Unix than about SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ps` to display current session processes with parent process id.

For example:

```
$ ps -jt
 PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
 2510  2511  2511  2511 pts/1     4890 Ss    1000   0:00 -bash
 2511  4343  4343  2511 pts/1     4890 Sl    1000   0:00 sqlplus              
 4343  4411  4411  2511 pts/1     4890 S     1000   0:00 /bin/bash
 4411  4890  4890  2511 pts/1     4890 R+    1000   0:00 ps -jt
$
```

Here bash process 4411 is child of 4343 which is sqlplus.

Comment: To clarify the options: `-j` is "display PPID and PGID", isn't it? and `-t` is "show only processes attached to a terminal"? The man ps page is so horrible, and the mac version of ps is slightly different to the linux version...

Comment: On CentOS 7  `-j`  is "job format" and `t` is "Select all processes associated with this terminal.".

Comment: OK, thanks. This translates apparently to `-jT` on macOSX.